# What is "image is oversized ..." bug?

Tags: disk-image

I have been seen this message since a long time:

> Warning: This image is oversized (which is a bug) and will not fit onto a standard 703MiB CD. However, you may still test it using a DVD, a USB drive, or a virtual machine.

Is this really a bug or the image size has just crossed the limit of the storage of a CD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

It has crossed the limit of CD storage, which is not desired ([so it is a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kubuntu-meta/+bug/1050726)). But there is also a bug about it [not being a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-cdimage/+bug/1289259).

Answer (score 0):

It just warns you that you can not use a CD for the installation, because the file is bigger than 700 MB, the capasity of a standard CD. But you can use a DVD or a USB drive instead.